# Kafka - Elastic Sink - AVRO schema data conversion issue for decimal/date values

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are seeing an issue where the decimal and date data isn't populated correctly on Elastic end... below is the whole context, Anyone has input, would greatly appreciate. Thanks

For class: "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector" using the below config

> value.converter: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"

Data arrives properly as below from the output of the stream

> "salesRevenue": 144800000

But when looking at message on the topic, shows as below

```
"salesRevenue": {
  "type": "Buffer",
  "data": [
    1,
    144,
    119,
    253,
    48,
    0
  ]
}
```

Schema for that field in registry is as below

```
{
      "default": null,
      "name": "salesRevenue",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
          "connect.parameters": {
            "connect.decimal.precision": "19",
            "scale": "4"
          },
          "connect.version": 1,
          "logicalType": "decimal",
          "precision": 19,
          "scale": 4,
          "type": "bytes"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Data outputted to ES is something like this

> salesRevenue": "AJiwXlCA"

Answer (score 0):

We have been able to resolve this by explicitly CASTing DECIMAL to> DOUBLE values on the ksql end before outputing to the final topic for Elastic sink connector consumption